# Can any one tell where i went wrong in validating an XML with XSD in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

Hi all i have my `XML` file as follows

Name of `XML` `XMLFile2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Product ProductID="123"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Product.xsd">
<ProductName>XYZ</ProductName>
</Product>
```

My `XSD` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Product"
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Product.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Product.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/Product.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Product">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ProductName" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="ProductID" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

This is my code

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath("XMLFile2.xml");
XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(strPath);
XmlValidatingReader v = new XmlValidatingReader(r);
v.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
v.ValidationEventHandler +=
new ValidationEventHandler(MyValidationEventHandler);
while (v.Read())
    {

    }
v.Close();

    if (isValid)
        Response.Write("Document is valid");
    else
        Response.Write("Document is invalid");
```

I am getting the following errors

```
Validation event
The targetNamespace parameter '' should be the same value as the targetNamespace 'http://tempuri.org/Product.xsd' of the schema.Validation event
The 'Product' element is not declared.Validation event
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProductID'.Validation event
The 'ProductName' element is not declared.Document is invalid
```

Can any one tell where i went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XSD is set to validate the `"http://tempuri.org/Product.xsd"` namespace, but your XML contains only elements from the `""` namespace.

You need to either (a) change the XML file to use the `"http://tempuri.org/Product.xsd"` namespace, or (b) change the XSD file to use the `""` namespace, depending on your user requirements.

Comment: Your XML file root element does not have an `xmlns` attribute, therefore all the elements belong to the empty namespace (`""`). By contrast, your XSD file has a `targetNamespace` attribute that specifies a specific namespace.

Comment: @User - your XML doesn't have a default namespace.

Comment: Hmm can any one tell what changes i would like to made now